# Why is "Chernobog" such a popular idea with fantasy creators?

Tags: history-of, mercedes-lackey, theology, chernobog, s-m-stirling

I recently read a short story by Stirling (in Turtledoves alternate universe collection) set in *The Peshawar Lancers* universe. In the very beginning, he mentions [Chernobog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobog) cult.

This kind of threw me for a loop, since I only associated Chernobog with Mercedes Lackey *Heirs of Alexandria* series.

Upon further research, the use of Chernobog [seems to be pretty popular in fantasy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobog#In_popular_culture) - in my impression, way more popular than is warranted given that the entity was a minor, virtually unknown power in an obscure part of Slavic pantheon (there were a lot more [well known and popular deities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavic_mythology) if one wants to borrow from ancient Slavs).

Is there any explanation for Chernobog's popularity?

Is there some known influence that people copy? Did any of the creators using Chernobog in their work explain WHY they picked Chernobog specifically?

I'm looking for facts/evidence, not guesses.

Comment: This is interesting. So far I've only found Chernobog in Neil Gaiman's _American Gods_, and I couldn't figure him out without the internet. It puzzles me too.

Comment: @AndresF. - I saw at least 9 uses in non-Russian fantasy on the Wiki.

Comment: Well, it sounds like Chernobyl, which I'm sure a lot more people have heard of...

Comment: @Izkata - hm. Interesting idea. Wonder if anything aside from Fantasia in that list precedes Chernobyl? If you can find a reference to ANY of the creators using that as inspiration, that's the kind of answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Does he appear in Douglas Adams?

Comment: I assume Cherryh used it because of a general interest in things Russian.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Russian_Stories_(C._J._Cherryh)

Comment: @b_jonas - not that I'm aware of. Why is Adams relevant?

Comment: @Ward - possible, but why choose such an obscure thing? Why not a slew of others? Heck, I haven't really heard of him till I read Lackey, and I knew the mythology better than average Westerner

Comment: Is this asking for the origin of popularity of the use of the name? Regardless of its initial "importance" in the Slavic pantheon, the idea of a "Dark Lord" is very useful to Fantasy themes. Why not use an existing historic name that doesn't have the repetition of "Satan" behind it?

Comment: @GorchestopherH - why use THAT specific one (out of a much wider and generally more well known pantheon - e.g. Veles which has Devil connotations as well). It can't be because it sounds more ominous, since to get the idea you have to be russian speaking.

Comment: What better deity to use in your work of fantasy than than one that is dark, unknown, obscure, and forgotten? I would think this grants the greatest creative license when compared to popular or better known ones with well defined roles. The purpose of the novels are not to adhere to the folklore, but to borrow something interesting that can be used as a creative device.

Comment: @GorchestopherH - typically, known entities are borrowed from other mythologies (with rare exceptions, you have Set and not Kherty).

Comment: Chernobog may be obscure, but smart people have a habit of picking up obscure facts.  Like I said, Cherryh probably used it because she seems to be interested in Russian history.  I'd heard of Chernobog from this book http://www.amazon.com/History-Eastern-Beginners-Writers-Readers/dp/0863162371 (which is an awesome book, btw).  It doesn't really surprise me that some of the early Disney creative types also knew about Russian mythology.

Comment: @DVK I believe the title detracts from this question. "Why is ______ so popular with _______ ?" isn't likely going to attract non-speculative answers. Rewording it to ask about the origins of its inclusion in popular modern works of fantasy may help.

Comment: @GorchestopherH - I specifically narrowed down to non-sepculative :) "Is there some known influence that people copy? Did any of the creators using Chernobog in their work explain WHY they picked Chernobog specifically?"

Comment: @Izkata The two words sound alike because they both begin with "black" in russian.  There are hundreds of other words that start with black

Comment: @Andrey - true. But "Chernobyl" is a word most westerners know.

Comment: The word Chernobog sounds like a radioactive swamp covered over with treacherous sphagnum moss; what's not to love?

Comment: I know! It wasn't Douglas Adams where I've heared of this.  It's Monty Python's Holy Grail, which has the rabbit of Caerbannog.

Comment: @b_jonas - huh? Caer Bannog is Welsh for "turreted castle".

Answer (score 4):

I think I may have a not-so-speculative answer. According to wikipedia article you've cited chernobog is a deity "...about whom much has been speculated but little can be said definitively." Since little is known about him, that gives  writers the freedom to make him into anything they want.

Tolkien did this in his fiction. He would take an obscure Anglo-Saxon word whose meaning was unclear, and simply give it a meaning of his own invention. For example the [orks were inspired by the Anlgo-Saxon word "orcneas"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orc_%28Middle-earth%29#Tolkien.27s_influences) used in Beowulf, and whose exact meaning is uncertain.

Comment: This is as non-speculative an answer as this question is going to get. Nice tidbit about orcneas.

Comment: You left out the part about swearing, goddamnit!